# compare two date using javascript and check

Tags: javascript, php

> this is my javascript function to compare two dates but it canot work correctly
>   how to convert these character values to date format?
>   my code is

function dateCompare()
    {

```
var fit_start_time  = $("#datepicker_from").val(); 
var fit_end_time    = $("#datepicker_to").val();


if((fit_start_time=="") || (fit_end_time==""))
{
alert ("Fill all fields");

}
else
{
if (fit_start_time > fit_end_time)
    {
    alert("invalid entry");
    $('#datepicker_to').val('');
    $('#datepicker_from').val(''); 
    }

}
}
```

> my html code is

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form6" id="form6" action="invoice_date_all.php" method="post">

    <div style="padding-top:4px;width:30px;float:left; ">From</div>
    <div style="width:172px;float:left; "> 
    <input type="text" id="datepicker_from" name="datepicker_from" onchange="dateCompare();" size="15"/>
    </div>
    <div  style="padding-top:4px;width:20px;float:left;  "> To</div>
    <div style="width:172px;float:left; "> 
    <input type="text" id="datepicker_to" name="datepicker_to" onchange="dateCompare();" size="15"/></div>

    <div class="label3"><input type="submit" value="Invoice Print"/></a></div>


        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: what is date format??

Comment: format is '08-jan-15'

Answer (score 0):

```
var fit_start_time  = $("#datepicker_from").val(); 
var fit_end_time    = $("#datepicker_to").val();
            var a = fit_start_time.split('/');
            var start = new Date(a[2], a[1] - 1, a[0]);
            var b = fit_end_time.split('/');
            var end = new Date(b[2], b[1] - 1, b[0]);
            if (start > end) {

            }
```

If your date separator is different than "/" then use your's in above code.

Comment: var start = new Date(a[2], a[1] - 1, a[0]); shows invalid date

Comment: In my code the date format is d/m/Y, if you have different then you have to adjust Date object accordingly.

Comment: i cann't find its solution? any one answer me?